# My application tries to save photos, however the following error appears on some phones when trying to save

Tags: kotlin

My application tries to save photos, however the following error appears on some phones when trying to save

```
androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: Failed to write or close the file
    androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture$3.onError(ImageCapture.java:685)
    androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.lambda$postError$1$ImageSaver(ImageSaver.java:263)
    androidx.camera.core.-$$Lambda$ImageSaver$2cOdLlQLf7oIXLW3Uxg7jMjL9J4.run(lambda)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6253)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using File Provider to save it? If not use File Provider . From API level 24 it requires File providers.SO,Study about how to use it? This [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) may help you. Thanks..

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm using file provider, it seems that this error occurs on older phones

Comment: @MatheusAngelicio try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856053/set-camerax-image-capture-file-path .

Comment: older phone , at which API Level. Mention API level.